# TArrray<FColor> to Texture2D in Unreal

Tags: unreal-4

I have a TArray of type FColor (I got it from the viewport) and I want to change that to a Texture2D object I can't find anything in the API's and I'm new to Unreal.

Thanks

Comment: Change it to a Texture2D - do you mean dynamically make a texture from the array of colors? If so, this is not a trivial task. What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I was trying to generate a texture from the viewport to be used on an object.
I think render target is the way to do it but I still want to know how I can change a bitmap (TArray<FColor>) to a Texture2D

Comment: Yes a rendertarget is a good way to do that. Bear in mind that while editor and runtime can create a rendertarget image, only the editor can save the image. Beyond that, actually writing a new Texture2D is likely to need C++ code - unless there's a sneaky way via materials and HLSL code.

Comment: I don't mind C++ I just don't know where to look in the docs

Comment: The process is kinda hidden. Try reading this, then adapting it for your needs: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/475962/dynamic-texture-memcpy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with C++

Then you should lock its data
Memcpy the data 
And update resources.

Here is a code snippet I am using currently:

````
    static UTexture2D* CreateTextureFromBGRA(FColor* data, int width, int height)
    {
        UTexture2D* Texture;

        Texture = UTexture2D::CreateTransient(width, height, PF_B8G8R8A8);
        if(!Texture)
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

#if WITH_EDITORONLY_DATA
        Texture->MipGenSettings = TMGS_NoMipmaps;
#endif
        Texture->NeverStream = true;

        Texture->SRGB = 0;

        FTexture2DMipMap& Mip = Texture->PlatformData->Mips[0];
        void* Data = Mip.BulkData.Lock(LOCK_READ_WRITE);

        FMemory::Memcpy(Data, data, width * height * 4);
        Mip.BulkData.Unlock();
        Texture->UpdateResource();

        return Texture;
    }


    static UTexture2D* CreateTextureFromDXT5(uint8* data, int width, int height)
    {
        UTexture2D* Texture;
        Texture = UTexture2D::CreateTransient(width, height, PF_DXT5);

        if (!Texture)
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

#if WITH_EDITORONLY_DATA
        Texture->MipGenSettings = TMGS_NoMipmaps;
#endif
        Texture->NeverStream = true;
        Texture->SRGB = 0;

        FTexture2DMipMap& Mip = Texture->PlatformData->Mips[0];
        void* Data = Mip.BulkData.Lock(LOCK_READ_WRITE);

        int32 NumBlocksX = width / GPixelFormats[PF_DXT5].BlockSizeX;
        int32 NumBlocksY = height / GPixelFormats[PF_DXT5].BlockSizeY;


        FMemory::Memcpy(Data, data, NumBlocksX * NumBlocksY * GPixelFormats[PF_DXT5].BlockBytes);

        Mip.BulkData.Unlock();
        Texture->UpdateResource();

        return Texture;
    }
```
````

Comment: I think I got around this using a render target after all. Still good to have a fast solution!

Comment: Idk about render target, but this solution shines only if done async to game-thread, the code is thread safe, the only thing is that you will have to remove Async flag from the texture when transferred to game-thread, otherwise it will not get garbage collected.